# My code is duplicating my wp posts

Tags: wordpress

I have written some php code that loops through the published posts on my wp site and when the Expiry Date (new field I added to each post) is <= to today's date, the post status is changed to draft.

It does change the status to draft however it duplicates the post. So I end up with 2 of the same posts, both set to "Draft".

I just want the original post status changed and that's it.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

The echo statements are just for me testing the code.

Below is some of my code:

[image: image of my code]

Comment: `the_ID()` echo the ID, but does not return. Change it to `get_the_ID()`

Comment: that works! thanks